# Leave K out cross validation shortcut

Tags: statistics

For splines and linear regressions there is this handy shortcut:

Let $\hat{f}$ be a spline estimate of a true function $f$, and let $\hat{f}_i^{[-i]}$ be the model fitted to all data except $y_i$. Then the ordinary leave-one-out cross validation score is

$V=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n ( \hat{f}_i^{[-i]} - y_i)^2$

However this can be inefficient, to compute so there is a well known (and used) shortcut:

$V=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\hat{f}_i)^2 / (1-A_{ii})^2$

Here $A_{ii}$ is called the influence or hat matrix

My question is, can this exact approach be used in chunks for $K$ fold cross validation as well? And if so under what conditions, if any, does this approach break down?

Thanks for any advice